# need to calculate sum between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need help for below logic, I have tried my end but not able to resolve this issue.
My Input table as below:

```
Months  Amount
Dec-15      720030
Jan-16      763236
Feb-16      795555
Mar-16      829252
Apr-16      856052
```

I need to calculate value as below and it will dynamic, because Months will increase based on current date.Output:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| Months      Amount      Formula         Expected Amount |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 15-Dec      720030      Dec-15          720030          |
| 16-Jan      763236      Dec-15+Jan-16   1483266         |
| 16-Feb      795555      Jan-16+Feb-16   1558791         |
| 16-Mar      829252      Feb-16+Mar-16   1624807         |
| 16-Apr      856052      Mar-16+Apr-16   1685304         |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: what is your desired output.?

Comment: Please mention desired output

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? You can use `LEAD` or `LAG` functions from 2012 onwards for this

Comment: What is the type of the `Months` column?

Comment: How do you plan on sorting your data? Your `months` column isn't going to cut it, if it's a varchar field.

Comment: need sort by Month only. i will make it Datetime format.

Comment: Hi Nitin, please give me query a try so that we may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using `LAG()`:

```
SELECT Months, Amount,
       CONVERT(varchar, MONTHS, 101) +     -- replace 101 with correct format mask
       CASE WHEN CONVERT(varchar, LAG(Months , '') OVER (ORDER BY Months), 101) <> ''
            THEN ' + ' + CONVERT(varchar, LAG(Months, '') OVER (ORDER BY Months), 101)
            ELSE '' END AS Formula,
       Amount + LAG (Amount, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Months) AS [Expected Amount]
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Have you observed the what the @Nitin.Gawade want to show and what your query gives.?

Comment: We don't know the answer to either because we don't know column types or what the actual data is.

Comment: Then you have posted your answer without proper data and requirement -:)

Answer (score 0):

I have first created a temp table which has additional column 'ID'. ID is created using ROW_NUMBER() function. Then, using a while loop I am traversing through table and adding previous value of the amount in the current amount

Code as below.

```
select month, amount, ROW_NUMBER() over(order by month) ID 
into New_Table from Your_Table

declare @a int
set @a = 1;
    while @a <= (select max(ID) from New_Table)
        begin
            IF @a = 1
            select month, amount, amount Expected_Amount from New_Table where ID = @a;
            ELSE
            select month, amount, amount + (select amount from New_Table where ID = (@a-1)) Expected_Amount from New_Table where ID = @a;
set @a = @a + 1;
end;
```